# Subschemes vs submanifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A smooth (resp. holomorphic) map  $f:M\to N$ of real manifolds (resp. complex manifolds) is said to be an immersion if it is a topological embedding and $T_pf:T_pM\to T_pN$ is injective for every $p\in M$. It is not hard to show  that in this case the image $f(M)$ is always a locally closed subset of $N$.

Now consider a morphism $g:X\to Y$ of schemes which is a topological embedding and $\mathcal{O}_{Y,g(p)} \to \mathcal{O}_{x,p}$ is surjective for every $p\in X$. Can we deduce that the image $g(X)$ is a locally closed subset of $Y$?

Any comments are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, we can't: see EGA  I 4.2.2!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the integral scheme $X={\rm Spec} \mathbb{Z}$. Let $\eta$ be the generic point. Then the natural morphism $\rm{Spec} (k(\eta)) \to X$ satisfies the condition, but with the image $\{\eta\}$ not locally closed.

Comment: Sorry, you mean $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta} \to \mathcal{O}_{Spec k(\eta), pt}$ is not surjective?

Comment: In your new example, why $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}= \mathbb{Q}[t]$? Note that $k(\eta)$ is just the residue field of of $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$, I think  my statement is easy to prove.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Z}[T]_{(0)}=\mathbb{Q}(t)$. Obviously, $t\not\in (0)$, so $t$ must be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[t]_{(0)}$.

Comment: I find the right example: let $X=Spec\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, the spectrum of the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at prime number $p$; let $\eta\in X$ be the generic point. $X$ is an integral (affine) scheme, $\dim_{Krull}X=1$, $\{\eta\}$ is an open subset of $X$, and $\mathcal{O}_{Spec\kappa(\eta),pt}\cong\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}\cong\mathbb{Z}_p$. Am I right, finally?

Comment: I don't think so. Firstly, since $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a DVR, $X$ has only two points and hence $dim X=0$. Secondly, if $X$ is an integral scheme, $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ should always be a field, and in your case it is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the field with $p$ element: do you know it? If $\dim_{Krull}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=0$, because it is Noetherian, then $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is Artinian: this is false! At the end: did you consult EGA I 4.2.2?

Comment: You are right. This is a counterexample. But we have $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}=\mathbb{Q}$ in your example, I insist.